# Spring OAuth2 - /oauth/authorize - User must be authenticated error

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to secure my rest api with authorization_code flow. I have a resource server and a separate authorization server. I use the oauth/token endpoint of the authorization server to generate the user token and use this token to access the resource server, which internally calls the /oauth/authorize endpoint of the authorization server. But when the authorize endpoint is called it gives an error

> org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.

Below is the configurations

**Authorization Server**

*WebSecurity*

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().disable()//
            .csrf().disable() //
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //
            .and().exceptionHandling() //
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)) //
            .and().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login") //
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator() {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientKeyGenerator clientKeyGenerator() {
        return new DefaultClientKeyGenerator();
    }

}
```

*AuthorizationServer*

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyTokenStore myTokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private MyClientDetailsService myClientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private MyApprovalStore myApprovalStore;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(myClientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), jwtAccessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(myTokenStore) //
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain) //
                .approvalStore(myApprovalStore) //
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new MyTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "123456".toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("123456"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class GlobalAuthenticationManagerConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

    }
}
```

*ResourceServer*

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyTokenStore myTokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable() //
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //
                .and().authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.cert");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(myTokenStore);
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

**Resource Server (Client)**

*WebSecurity*

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated() //
                .and().oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-auth:
            client-name: custom-auth
            client-id: org1
            client-secret: 123456
            scope: openid
            provider: custom-auth
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          custom-auth:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8180/oauth/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8180/oauth/authorize
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8180/user/me
```

I have seen the oauth/authorize request sent to the authorization server and the bearer token is included in the request.

This is a fully rest API based and I do not have any pages.

**Edited**

*I have been looking within the spring and see that, FilterChainProxy is invoked for resources which internally invokes the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter and the Authentication object is set into the RequestContext. But for /oauth/authorize I do not see  FilterChainProxy getting invoked, is there anyway I can get FilterChainProxy to work for /oauth/authorize.*

Comment: I do not want a form login, I only need to generate tokens using the oauth/token endpoint. I don't want any pages.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you want to use instead of form login? Do you want basic authentication? You have to use any authentication type on your authorization server.

Comment: I have already logged in using password grant flow and I am sending the token as Bearer in Authorization header in the /oauth/authorize request. So can't the user be authenticated using the Bearer token?

Comment: If you are already logged in, your resource server shouldn't call the `/oauth/authorize` again.  The resource server only calls this endpoint, if your request doesn't contain a  token or it contains an invalid token. Show your request to your resource server with HTTP headers.

Comment: I am logged in at the AuthServer and have the token generated from the AuthServer, but still my ResourceServer is not authorised. So for the user to be authorised at the ResourceServer i am calling /oauth/authorize

Comment: Your edit shows that your resource server tries to authenticate the user. You do not need to call `/oauth/authorize` again, it is already used with your authorization server.